# How to answer using "had better" form for a positive answer?

Tags: grammar

When give an answer using "had better" form, should we add the verb after "had better", such as: "Yes, we'd better study". or just to answer: "Yes, we'd better. "
For question number 3 and 5, thanks[image]

Comment: You don't need to repeat the verb - since it has already been stated in the question and is obvious. This is a form of [ellipsis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis) which is very common in English.

Comment: You have done your homework correctly but we don't really do homework here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is grammatically acceptable. In general, adding optional words makes a sentence more formal, so if our conversation went:

> You: Should I study for the exam?
>
> Me: Yes, you'd better study.

That would sound more formal than if I say "Yeah, you'd better."

"had better" in this usage is already informal. So to my (American) ears, using a more formal version by adding extra repetition sounds odd. I would be more likely to omit the repetition and use "yeah" when using "you'd better."

If I was trying to be formal, I would say "you should __" or "I recommend that you __" instead.

Answer (score 0):

In all of these examples, dropping the verb is fine because it was just spoken. There are some cases where it would be necessary to say it, though. If your "had better" sentence were *not* a response to something the other person just said—like if I start the conversation by saying "You'd better...," then if there were no previous words exchanged, the other person would say "I'd better what?"

Also, if the question mentioned a choice between *two* (or more) verbs, the answer would have to repeat one.

> "Should I study or cook?"
> "You'd better study."